# How to increase the size of the canvas of IPE extensible drawing editor which is used for Latex diagrams?

Tags: ipe

I am not able to increase the size of the canvas of the IPE extensible drawing editor. Any help will be great as my image is not fitting in the default canvas size of IPE editor. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The size of the canvas in Ipe can be changed using a style sheet. This is a separate file in xml format where you can add definitions to be used in your Ipe documents, for example color definitions or pen widths. One of the settings that you can add in such a file is the paper and frame size.

To use these settings you need to create a file in the same folder as your Ipe document. The settings file needs to be saved with the extension `.isy`. Then, when you open your document in Ipe, select *Style sheets* from the *Edit* menu (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>). Click on <kbd>Add</kbd> and find your style sheet file. The new style will be applied automatically. If you want to modify the style file and reload then you can delete it from the menu and add it again.

Example `.isy` file:

```xml
<ipestyle name="customsize">
   <layout paper="1612 400" origin="0 0" frame="1612 400"/>
</ipestyle>
```

Result, show a canvas with reduced height and increased width:

[image]

You can find more information about style sheets on https://ipe.otfried.org/manual/manual_stylesheets.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marjin.. :)